# Can I include code from one file to the next, similar to Includes in html

Tags: java, android, include

Ok, Please be gentle and kind.  I am taking an Android Programming class in college and its our teachers first semester so he is learning as we are... Nothing against him, he's a good teacher, just doesn't know the answer.

I don't know how to put this in Android/java language so here goes...

Is there a way to use something similar to Includes, in web design, in Android.  I am looking to add similar java code from one activity to the next, can i make a file that if i change this one file it will change in all the files its included it.

I know it can be done with the XML files but i couldn't find anything to show that it can be done in the actually coding... but then again i don't know the correct terminology.  Please any help would be great.  And thank you for taking the time to read and answer me.  I apologize if this was somewhere else, I just couldn't find it.. Thanks again

Comment: Have you coded in plain vanilla Java before trying Android?

Comment: I would feel better about computer science courses that taught bedrock things that wouldn't change in five years rather than the language du jour.

Comment: If by "includes in web design", you're referring to Html, classic ASP style, or css/script includes; I'd strongly recommend learning a little more about standard Java programming, Object Oriented Programming, and basic code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Put anything you wish to "include" in Java classes, then import them. http://leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html

Comment: I should add, since it's Java you might want to do some object oriented design first. Think about how the code you want to include could be made into a reusable object. And if you do, you can also use inheritance to reuse code, besides imports.

Answer (score 0):

Android Programming class! I would've loved that in University...

Regardless, if you're using Eclipse for your IDE, it should pickup any changes from your java imports automatically. If you choose to refactor other java classes within your project, a rename for example (with "Update All References"), will update all references to that class across your project.

You could also use Maven (dependency management) to pull the latest third-party (or other) .jars at build time, if that's applicable to what your needs are.

:)